# -webkit-transform issue with Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, mobile-website

Further to my earlier question regarding the detection of colliding elements in jQuery, I have written some custom jQuery code that handles this. Everything works fine in Google Chrome, and works as expected.

However, under Mobile Safari on iOS 5, the settings are not reflected. Here's the sample jQuery code for the animation:

```
if(this_position.top <= docked_element.bottom && ($this.html() != fake_persistent.html()))
{
    var new_top = this_position.top - fake_persistent.outerHeight();
    fake_persistent.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + new_top + 'px, 0)');
}
```

While the transform doesn't appear to work, if I stop scrolling on the window, the element is positioned correctly. It's a little difficult to explain, but if you look at this page in Chrome, and then in Mobile Safari, you'll see what I mean > http://ben-major.co.uk/labs/contact-app/

Comment: interesting issue, i've been experiencing the same problem...

Comment: Javascript doesn't get executed on iOS 5 after a touch event starts until the scroll event stops (One of the drawbacks of the fast and smooth native scrolling - the entire scrollable element is rendered in memory, not just the visible portion)

Try using actual fixed position styling for ios5 and keep your current one if it works for iOS 4